# Access fields of CheckBoxComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a [CheckBoxComboBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and) where I want to get fields of checked items so I do something like:

```
foreach (var currentChecked in cboDesignStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked))
{
    var a = currentChecked.ComboBoxItem;
}
```

So `var a` result is :

[image]

My question is, how can I access this fields ? I want to get property `Name` so I try

```
 var a = currentChecked.ComboBoxItem.Name;
```

But I can't it only let this:

[image]

How can I access this field

Note: variable on foreach "currentChecked" throws `ComboBoxItem` as `ObjectSelectionWrapper`

[image]

ObjectSelectionWrapper Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data;

namespace MyProject.Utility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used together with the ListSelectionWrapper in order to wrap data sources for a CheckBoxComboBox.
    /// It helps to ensure you don't add an extra "Selected" property to a class that don't really need or want that information.
    /// </summary>
    public class ObjectSelectionWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObjectSelectionWrapper(T item, ListSelectionWrapper<T> container)
            : base()
        {
            _Container = container;
            _Item = item;
        }


        #region PRIVATE PROPERTIES

        /// <summary>
        /// Used as a count indicator for the item. Not necessarily displayed.
        /// </summary>
        private int _Count = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// Is this item selected.
        /// </summary>
        private bool _Selected = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// A reference to the wrapped item.
        /// </summary>
        private T _Item;
        /// <summary>
        /// The containing list for these selections.
        /// </summary>
        private ListSelectionWrapper<T> _Container;

        #endregion

        #region PUBLIC PROPERTIES

        /// <summary>
        /// An indicator of how many items with the specified status is available for the current filter level.
        /// Thaught this would make the app a bit more user-friendly and help not to miss items in Statusses
        /// that are not often used.
        /// </summary>
        public int Count
        {
            get { return _Count; }
            set { _Count = value; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// A reference to the item wrapped.
        /// </summary>
        public T Item
        {
            get { return _Item; }
            set { _Item = value; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The item display value. If ShowCount is true, it displays the "Name [Count]".
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                string Name = null;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Container.DisplayNameProperty))
                    Name = Item.ToString();
                else if (Item is DataRow) // A specific implementation for DataRow
                    Name = ((DataRow)((Object)Item))[_Container.DisplayNameProperty].ToString();
                else
                {
                    PropertyDescriptorCollection PDs = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Item);
                    foreach (PropertyDescriptor PD in PDs)
                        if (PD.Name.CompareTo(_Container.DisplayNameProperty) == 0)
                        {
                            Name = (string)PD.GetValue(Item).ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                    {
                        PropertyInfo PI = Item.GetType().GetProperty(_Container.DisplayNameProperty);
                        if (PI == null)
                            throw new Exception(String.Format(
                                      "Property {0} cannot be found on {1}.",
                                      _Container.DisplayNameProperty,
                                      Item.GetType()));
                        Name = PI.GetValue(Item, null).ToString();
                    }
                }
                return _Container.ShowCounts ? String.Format("{0} [{1}]", Name, Count) : Name;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The textbox display value. The names concatenated.
        /// </summary>
        public string NameConcatenated
        {
            get { return _Container.SelectedNames; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether the item is selected.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return _Selected; }
            set
            {
                if (_Selected != value)
                {
                    _Selected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
                    OnPropertyChanged("NameConcatenated");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, declaring a variable in a loop means you wont be able to access anything outside the loop.  Next, apparently you have `DataRows` in there which implies a `DataSource`.  If so dig onto each (or it) and get the data you want.  Note you are drilling for fields *not* properties

Comment: Also, fun fact, things like a CBO or ListBox collections store objects because literally anything can be stored there from `DataRow`s to instances of your classes.  So when you use `var` your variable is defined as object which has just those few props. Avoid `var`. If you cast to a `DataRow` (assuming that **is** what is in there), you can get typed data back easily: `DateTime dt = myDR.Field<DateTime>("YourDateTimeColName")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ComboBoxItem is an Object.  As Nat said earlier, if you cast the object to your expected class, you can then reference the properties.

```
var itemName = ((Utility.ObjectSelectionWrapper<DataRow>)currentChecked.ComboBoxItem).Name;
```

Comment: That's the problem, you are correct `ComboBoxItem` is an object.  I don't know what is that expected class. As you can see in my last picture "ComboBoxItem" is an `ObjectSelectionWrapper<DataRow>`, but I don't have an idea what type of cast I need to use in order to access fields.

Comment: I update my question with `ObjectSelectionWrapper<DataRow>` class. It may help